# Does numpy always create a copy when writing self-referenced data

Tags: python, numpy

Consider this code

```
k = 1000000000
a = np.arange(k)
a[:-1] = a[1:]
```

while one can devise some code that gets this done without a copy array, I suspect that numpy creates a copy of the affect part of the array for this operation, correct?

Would this also be the case, when the source and target range do not overlap, like so:

```
k = 1000000000
a = np.arange(k)
a[:k//2] = a[k//2:]
```

This could easily be done in place.

Comment: what makes you think that numpy would make a full copy?

Comment: First, you should read up on basic `numpy`, especially the distinction between `view` and copy, and basic v. advanced indexing.  Second, this is Python.  So the RHS side is evaluated first, and then the assignment.  In short there is some buffering going, but its with a view.  The overlap or not does not change things.

Comment: To convince yourself that this is not the case compare the timing of `a = np.arange(10_000_000)` and then `a[2:12] = a[0:10]`. The second one is orders of magnitude faster, would this be possible with a full copy? ;)

Comment: @mozway okay, it will only copy the affected area, but it will copy that nontheless, right? how about the non-overlapping case?

Comment: if you downvote, I'd appreciate a hint why you think this question is "poor" (and not just because I'm perhaps seemingly not satisfied with a provided answer).

Comment: @Xaser this part, I don't know. You would need to look at the specific python implementation. This might be different in C-python or other variants.

Answer (score 1):

This is buffered:

```
In [112]: a = np.arange(12)
     ...: a[2:12] = a[0:10]
In [113]: a
Out[113]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Compare this to a unbuffered result:

```
In [114]: a = np.arange(12)
     ...: for i in range(10):
     ...:     a[2+i] = a[i]
     ...: 
In [115]: a
Out[115]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

`a[2]` is changed before it is used in the copy.

`a[0:10]` is a `view`

Forcing a copy does slow things down, though not much for this small case:

```
In [116]: %%timeit
     ...: a = np.arange(12)
     ...: a[2:12] = a[0:10]
     ...: 
     ...: 
2.56 µs ± 15.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
In [117]: %%timeit
     ...: a = np.arange(12)
     ...: a[2:12] = a[0:10].copy()
     ...: 
     ...: 
3.41 µs ± 9.74 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Comment: You have demonstrated that numpy correctly handles the problem of overlapping source and destination. There's multiple ways of achieving this, however, either by using a buffer space or by smartly copying elements in the right order. It does not answer the question whether a buffer is used in all cases (overlapping and non-overlapping)

Comment: The `=` is handled by Python, not some "smart" numpy code.  `numpy` runs in Python.  Your assignment is `a.__setitem__(slice(2,12), a.__getitem__(slice(0,10))`.  The `getitem` is evaluated before the `set`.

Comment: that actually is a good point.

Comment: Actually, `__getitem__` might return a view type object, without actually having copied any data yet, right? so it would still be possible to handle this without buffering.

Comment: Without studying the c code I don't know how to pin down the amount if buffering.  The view references the same data buffer, but it isn't overwritten in the assignment.

Comment: With some carefully constructed timings I see evidence that it is doing some extra buffering when copying from a self view, but the effect isn't large.  I don't think this kind of copy is frequent enough to merrit special optimization, just enough care to get the values right.

Comment: I actually did some digging in the c code and while I do not understand it fully, there's certainly checking for memory overlap between source and destination going on.